# Swagger ignores parts of the mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-restcontroller, springfox

I have a `@RestController` with `@RequestMapping("/v1/loja")` and a method annotated with `@GetMapping("/{code}")`. Besides this, the context path is `/loja`. 
With that in mind, the expected mapping is `/loja/v1/loja/{code}`, but the UI shows `/loja/v1/{code}` which results in a bad request.

chrome dev tools confirms that the UI is calling the wrong endpoint: `http://localhost:9103/loja/v1/2`

I'm using spring fox swagger with Spring boot, Java 12 OpenJDK

dependencies:

```
  implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfoxSwaggerVersion}") {
    exclude module: 'swagger-annotations'
    exclude module: 'swagger-models'
  }
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springfoxSwaggerVersion}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-spring-webmvc:${springfoxSwaggerVersion}"
  implementation "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:${swaggerVersion}"
  implementation "io.swagger:swagger-models:${swaggerVersion}"
```

```
springfoxSwaggerVersion=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
swaggerVersion=1.5.24
```

Is this a bug or there could be a wrong/missing configuration or something like this?

**UPDATE**

I've decided to add something else to the path on the controller level, and it seems that swagger is messing things up.

I changed the Request mapping to `@RequestMapping("/v1/lojaa")` and the result was `/loja/v1a/{code}`

**UPDATE 2**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/loja")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Api
public class StoreController {

  @GetMapping("/{codigo_loja}")
  @ApiOperation(value = "get store by code", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Store not found"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Store found")
  })
  public ResponseEntity<StoreResponse> getStoreByCode(@PathVariable("codigo_loja") final Integer code) {

    ... some logic ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your RestController code?

Comment: yes, just a sec

Comment: What happens when you try to access this link on google chrome:  http://localhost:9103/v1/loja/2

Comment: Based on your controller code, swagger is showing correct.

Comment: @Zeusox If you mean localhost:9103/loja/v1/loja/2 it finds the resource. But on localhost:9103/v1/loja/2 is not found too because this mapping does not exist.

Comment: @want2learn If swagger is showing correctly, then spring would be mapping the controller incorrectly (it is not). The expected mapping exists, if I use Postman, Insomnia or even chrome, instead of swagger, it works fine. As far as I could understand, the problem is Swagger. I've been using swagger for a few weeks and this is the first time this problem happens.